# How to load values to page while scrolling the page

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a table named "User"  with more than 3k rows in MySql database.I want to fetch the database while scrolling the page(As like Facebook news feeds). I surfed for a long time but I can't get it. hoping positive response as soon as possible.

thank you!

Comment: make use of `.scrollTop(), .height() with use of jQuery.ajax()` methods to get it done.

Comment: am new to jQuery, could i get a link for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what did you mean:

Database Table

```
CREATE TABLE messages(
mes_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
msg TEXT);
```

load_data.php

When we are scrolling down a webpage, the script($(window).scroll) finds that you are `at the bottom and calls the last_msg_funtion(). Take a look at $.post("") eg: $.post("load_data.php?action=get&last_msg_id=35")`

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$last_msg_id=$_GET['last_msg_id'];
$action=$_GET['action'];

if($action <> "get")
{
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
function last_msg_funtion() 
{ 
var ID=$(".message_box:last").attr("id");
$('div#last_msg_loader').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');
$.post("load_data.php?action=get&last_msg_id="+ID,

function(data){
if (data != "") {
$(".message_box:last").after(data); 
}
$('div#last_msg_loader').empty();
});
}; 

$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
last_msg_funtion();
}
}); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
include('load_first.php'); //Include load_first.php 
?>
<div id="last_msg_loader"></div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}

else
{
include('load_second.php'); //include load_second.php
}
?>
```

load_first.php
Contains PHP code to load 20 rows form the message table.

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY mes_id DESC LIMIT 20");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$msgID= $row['mes_id'];
$msg= $row['msg'];
?>
<div id="<?php echo $msgID; ?>" class="message_box" > 
<?php echo $msg; ?>
</div> 
<?php
} 
?>
```

load_second.php
Contains PHP code to load 5 rows less than last_msg_id form the message table.

```
<?php
$last_msg_id=$_GET['last_msg_id'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE mes_id < '$last_msg_id' ORDER BY mes_id DESC LIMIT 5");
$last_msg_id="";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$msgID= $row['mes_id'];
$msg= $row['msg']; 
?>
<div id="<?php echo $msgID; ?>" class="message_box" > 
<?php echo $msg; 
?>
</div>
<?php
} 
?>
```

CSS

```
body
{
font-family:'Georgia',Times New Roman, Times, serif;
font-size:18px;
}
.message_box
{
height:60px;
width:600px; 
border:dashed 1px #48B1D9; 
padding:5px ;
}
#last_msg_loader
{
text-align: right;
width: 920px;
margin: -125px auto 0 auto;
}
.number
{
float:right; 
background-color:#48B1D9; 
color:#000; 
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Take a look at [live demo](http://demos.9lessons.info/load_data_scroll.php) and scroll down.

Regards,
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://jscroll.com/ or just google for "jQuery load content while scrolling" or "jQuery infinite scroll" for other alternatives.

Comment: the reference doesn't meet my requirement

Comment: Sorry mate, tried to post a detailed answer for half an hour now. But Stackoverflow tells me, that my answer could not be updated due to an unknown error.

Comment: don't mention sorry, It's ok.